# What shells were used on early unix systems?

Tags: shell, history, thompson-shell

[According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_shells#General_characteristics), the Bourne shell was introduced in 1977 and C shell in 1978, but unix itself dates back to 1969.

If you were using a unix system before 1977, what shell would you have been using?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The original Unix shell was the [Thompson shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_shell).  There was also a derivative of it called the [PWB shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PWB_shell).

(Source: [Historic Unix shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Historic) at Wikipedia)

Comment: As an interesting tidbit, Newham & Rosenblatt mention (in _Learning the bash Shell_) that the only Bourne shell feature not supported by bash is the ^ circumflex as a synonym for the pipe, included in sh for backward compatibility with the Thompson shell.

Comment: [see also: `osh`](http://v6shell.org/)

Comment: https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/hist.html mentions that "then came a small set of user-level utilities: the means to copy, print, delete, and edit files, and of course a simple command interpreter (shell)"